Does General Relativity predict anisotropic inertial mass?
Following Treder's article Zur Anisotropie träger Massen in tensoriellen Gravitationstheorien (On the anisotropy of inertial masses in tensorial theories of gravity), for which I have found no translation into English,
does General Relativity predict anisotropic inertial mass?
Anisotropic inertial masses is ruled out by experiments up to very high precision. See Hughes-Drever Experiment Wikipedia page for reference.

To my knowledge no such prediction exists. It would be useful though if you'd at least give a translated summary of the article; that would help us better understand the context of the question.

Keep in mind the entire website is English based, so you're making your own life difficult by posting a link to a paper in German which is also behind a paywall.

Does General Relativity predict anisotropic inertial mass? I don’t remember either MTW or Weinberg discussing any such prediction in their textbooks, so I doubt it.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine Sorry but I do not have the translated version and I cannot translated myself, it's a publication in Annalen der Physik.
